NW.JS wont get Fullscreen whatever i did
I installed NWJS 0.44 on my Raspberry Pi 5... It works fine but the problem is it won't get fullscreen.. like its forced to be 854x480 ( Construct 2 Defualt Window Size ), I enabled kiosk thing mode but still the 854x480 windowed... It doesn't have window frame.. if I make it automatically fullscreens it will just crop the screen and shows in 854x480 ( but when I show a alert also shows a part of it on side of canvas )... I asked chatgpt, and he gave me some resolution changing codes and force window size changing but that just crashed the nwjs and didn't work... So if anyone know how can i force fullscreen or just set the resolution of display to 854x480 with screen gets stretched.
the resizable window and window frame is enabled
i dont think its problem of construct 2.. HELP NO BRAKE game will get cropped after fullscreen too on nwjs

Have you tried a blank NW.js project, without using Construct 2. It sounds less like an NW.js problem, and more of a Construct 2 problem.

i tried redirecting to a html not construct game & classicube but the fullscreen is glitchy
